# Rotate a singly linked list in Java

Tags: java, rotation, linked-list, singly-linked-list

My functions:

```
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;


public class LinkedList {
    private Node head;
    private int listCount;

    // konstruktor na povrzanata lista
    public LinkedList()
    {
        // ova e prazna lista, pa zatoa 'head' pokazuva kon nov jazok bez elementi (null)
        head = new Node(null);
        listCount = 0;
    }

    // dodavame element (data) na krajot od listata
    public void add(Object data)
    {
        Node temp = new Node(data);
        Node current = head;
        head.setData(temp.getData());

        // pocnuvajki od 'head' (pocetniot element) pominuvame niz site lemenenti
        while(current.getNext() != null)
        {
            current = current.getNext();
        }

        current.setNext(temp);

        // go zgolemuvame brojot na elementi vo listata
        listCount++;
    }

    // dodavame element (data) na posebno opredelena pozicija (index)
    public void add(Object data, int index)
    {
        Node temp = new Node(data);
        Node current = head;
        head.setData(temp.getData());

        // odime do baraniot index, ili do posledniot element od listata (do koj stigneme prvo)
        for (int i = 1; i < index && current.getNext() != null; i++)
        {
            current = current.getNext();
        }

        // go postavuvame sledniot element na novata jazla 
        // da pokazuva kon sledniot element na ovaa jazla
        temp.setNext(current.getNext());

        // a sega go postavuvame sledniot element na ovaa jazla
        // da pokazuva kon novata jazla
        current.setNext(temp);

        // go nakacuvame vkupniot broj na elementi vo listata
        listCount++;
    }

    // vraka element na opredelena pozicija vo listata
    public Object get(int index)
    {
        if(index <= 0)
        {
            return null;
        }

        Node current = head.getNext();

        for(int i = 1; i < index; i++)
        {
            if(current.getNext() == null)
            {
                return null;
            }

            current = current.getNext();
        }

        return current.getData();
    }

    // go vrakame brojot na elementi vo listata
    public int size()
    {
        return listCount;
    }

    // go brisime elementot na opredelenata pozicija vo listata
    public boolean remove(int index)
    {
        if(index < 1 || index > size())
        {
            return false;
        }

        Node current = head;

        for(int i = 1; i < index; i++)
        {
            if(current.getNext() == null)
            {
                return false;
            }
            current = current.getNext();
        }

        current.setNext(current.getNext().getNext());

        // go namaluvame brojot na elementi vo listata
        listCount--;

        return true;
    }

    public boolean contains(Object data)
    {
        Node temp = new Node(data);
        Node current = head;

        for(int i = 0; i < size(); i++)
        {
            if(temp.getData().equals(current.getData()))
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                current = current.getNext();
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public Node inserAfter(Object data, Node n)
    {
        Node temp = new Node(data);
        Node current = n.getNext();

        temp.setNext(current);
        n.setNext(temp);

        return temp;
    }

    public void rotateLeft()
    {
        Node temp = head;
        //head = head.getNext();

        //Node tail = head.getNext();

        if (head != null) {                       //otherwise it is empty list
            //Node temp = head;
            if (head.getNext() != null) {           //otherwise it is single item list
                head = head.getNext();
            }
        }

        Node tail;
        if (head.getNext() != null) {
            //more than 2 items in the list
            tail = head.getNext();
        } else {
            //only 2 items in the list
            tail = head;
        }

        while(tail.getNext() != null)
        {
            if (tail.getNext() != null) {
                tail = tail.getNext();
            }
            //tail = tail.getNext();
        }
        tail.setNext(temp);
        temp.setNext(null);
    }

    public void rotateRight()
    {
        Node temp = null;
        Node current = head;

        while(current.getNext() != null)
        {
            temp = current;
            current = current.getNext();
        }
        current.setNext(head);
        head = current;
        temp.setNext(null);
    }

    public void reverse()
    {
        Node reversedPart = null;
        Node current = head;

        while(current != null)
        {
            Node next = current.next;
            current.next = reversedPart;
            reversedPart = current;
            current = next;
        }
        head = reversedPart;
    }

    public Node copyList(Node source)
    {
        Node copyHead = null;
        Node copyTail = null;

        Node temp = new Node(source);
        Node current = head.getNext();

        for(int i = 0; i < size(); i++)
        {
            Node newNode = new Node(temp.getData());
            if(copyHead == null)
            {
                copyHead = newNode;
                copyTail = copyHead;
            }
            else
            {
                copyTail.setNext(newNode);
                copyTail = copyTail.getNext();
            }
        }

        return copyHead;
    }

    public Object setDataIndexOf(Object data, int index)
    {
        Node node = nodeAt(index);

        if(node == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        else
        {
            Object old = node.getData();
            node.setData(data);
            return old;
        }
    }

    public Object dataAt(int index)
    {
        Node current = head.getNext();

        if(index < 1 || index > size())
        {
            return null;
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < index; i ++)
        {
            if(i != index - 1)
            {
                current = current.getNext();
            }
        }

        return current.getData();
    }

    public Node nodeAt(int index)
    {
        Node current = head.getNext();

        if(index < 1 || index > size())
        {
            return null;
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < index; i++)
        {
            if(i != index - 1)
            {
                current = current.getNext();
            }
        }

        return current;
    }

    public int indexOf(Object data)
    {
        Node temp = new Node(data);
        Node current = head.getNext();

        for(int i = 0; i < size(); i++)
        {
            if(current.getData().equals(temp.getData()))
            {
                return i;
            }
            current = current.getNext();
        }

        return -1;
    }

    public Object min()
    {
        Integer min = (Integer)head.getData();
        Node current = head;

        while(current.getNext() != null)
        {
            if((Integer)current.getData() < min)
            {
                min = (Integer)current.getData();
            }
            current = current.getNext();
        }

        return min;
    }

    public Object max()
    {
        Integer max = (Integer)head.getData();
        Node current = head;

        while(current.getNext() != null)
        {
            if((Integer)current.getData() > max)
            {
                max = (Integer)current.getData();
            }
            current = current.getNext();
        }

        return max;
    }

    public void removeSecondAppear(Object data)
    {
        Node temp = new Node(data);
        Node current = head;
        Node previous = null;

        boolean found = false;

        while(current != null)
        {                       
            if(current.getData().equals(temp.getData()) && current.getData() != null)
            {
                if(found == true)
                {
                    previous.setNext(current.getNext());
                    break;
                }
                else if(found == false)
                {
                    found = true;
                }

            }
            else{
                found = false;
            }

            previous = current;
            current = current.getNext();
        }

    }

    public String toString()
    {
        Node current = head.getNext();
        String output = "";

        while(current != null)
        {
            output += "[" + current.getData().toString() + "]";
            current = current.getNext();
        }

        return output;
    }
}
```

My node:

```
public class Node {
    Node next;

    Object data;

    public Node(Object _data)
    {
        next = null;
        data = _data;
    }

    public Node(Object _data, Node _next)
    {
        next = _next;
        data = _data;
    }

    public Object getData()
    {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(Object _data)
    {
        data = _data;
    }

    public Node getNext()
    {
        return next;
    }

    public void setNext(Node _next)
    {
        next = _next;
    }
}
```

I'm trying to create a function to rotate a singly linked in list in Java. I have made two functions for left and right.

My left function seems to work, but not fully. For example. If my list contains the elements: 1 2 3

Then my rotateLeft will make the list into 2 3. The 1 will be gone. But it should come on the position of previous 3.

As for the rotateRight, the function is not functioning properly for some reason, been trying a few hours and can't find the solution.

```
    LinkedList LL = new LinkedList();

    LL.add("1");
    LL.add("2");
    LL.add("3");
    LL.add("4");
    LL.add("4");
    LL.add("5");
    LL.rotateLeft();
```

2, 3, 4, 4, 5, null is the output. My add method is the following:

```
public void add(Object data)
{
    Node temp = new Node(data);
    Node current = head;

    while(current.getNext() != null)
    {
        current = current.getNext();
    }

    current.setNext(temp);

    listCount++;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this correction:

```
public void rotateLeft() {
  if (head != null) {                       //otherwise it is empty list
    Node temp = head;
    if (head.getNext() != null) {           //otherwise it is single item list
        head = head.getNext();
    }

    Node tail;
    if (head.getNext() != null) {
        //more than 2 items in the list
        tail = head.getNext();
    } else {
        //only 2 items in the list
        tail = head;
    }
    while (tail.getNext() != null) {
        if (tail.getNext() != null) {
            tail = tail.getNext();
        }
    }
    tail.setNext(temp);
    temp.setNext(null);
  }
}

public void rotateRight() {
  if (head != null) {                       //otherwise it is empty list
    Node tail = null;
    Node current = head;

    while (current.getNext() != null) {
        tail = current;
        current = current.getNext();
    }
    if (tail != null) {             //otherwise it is single item list
        tail.setNext(null);
        current.setNext(head);
        head = current;
    }
  }
}
```

You also did not treat the case of empty list, single item list or only 2 items in the list.

EDIT:

code:

```
public class LinkedList {

    Node head;

    public LinkedList() {
        this.head = null;
    }

    public LinkedList(Node head) {
        this.head = head;
    }

    public void rotateLeft() {
        System.out.println("<-");
        if (head != null) { // otherwise it is empty list
            Node temp = head;
            if (head.getNext() != null) { // otherwise it is single item list
                head = head.getNext();
            }

            Node tail;
            if (head.getNext() != null) {
                // more than 2 items in the list
                tail = head.getNext();
            } else {
                // only 2 items in the list
                tail = head;
            }
            while (tail.getNext() != null) {
                if (tail.getNext() != null) {
                    tail = tail.getNext();
                }
            }
            tail.setNext(temp);
            temp.setNext(null);
        }
    }

    public void rotateRight() {
        System.out.println("->");
        if (head != null) { // otherwise it is empty list
            Node tail = null;
            Node current = head;

            while (current.getNext() != null) {
                tail = current;
                current = current.getNext();
            }
            if (tail != null) { // otherwise it is single item list
                tail.setNext(null);
                current.setNext(head);
                head = current;
            }
        }
    }

    public void printList() {
        Node cursor = head;
        while (cursor != null) {
            System.out.print(cursor.data + ", ");
            cursor = cursor.getNext();
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    public void add(Object data) {
        Node temp = new Node(data);

        if (head == null) {
            head = temp;
        } else {
            Node current = head;

            while (current.getNext() != null) {
                current = current.getNext();
            }

            current.setNext(temp);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LinkedList r = new LinkedList();
        r.add(1);
        r.add(2);
        r.add(3);
        r.add(4);
        r.add(4);
        r.add(5);
        r.printList();
        r.rotateLeft();
        r.printList();
        r.rotateLeft();
        r.printList();
        r.rotateRight();
        r.printList();
        r.rotateRight();
        r.printList();
    }

}
```

output:

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 
<-
2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 1, 
<-
3, 4, 4, 5, 1, 2, 
->
2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 1, 
->
1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5,
```

Comment: Please post your complete code with my correction and with some wrong output. I have checked that, and it is running correctly.

Comment: is that what you meant?

Comment: Yes, but it still works for me. :) Except, i'm not sure how do you initialize the head after creating an empty LinkedList.
Check updated answer with full code and correct output...

Comment: I created the main outside the LinkedList class. Do you think that could be the problem ?

Comment: I think no. Show me the constructor.

Comment: the constructor of what exactly? The other class I have is only for Main. Nothin else inside it.

Comment: Constructor of LinkedList, I suppose you initialize the head in it. Or where do you initialize it?

Comment: Yes the constructor was one problem. The head was always `null` which I fixed now. It no longer outputs `null`, but there is  another problems. Now it doesn't output the correct element. For example, if I have 1, 3, 4, 5. My program outputs: 3, 4, 5, 5. (for left rotation) what could be the problem in this case?

Comment: I really need to see the complete code. Or check the difference to my class.

Comment: Is it fine, if I upload the whole classes (Node + LinkedList) in pastebin?

Comment: I have added the full singly-linked list class.

Comment: Your LinkedList is not empty after initialization. It contains one Node with null. When you are rotating objects in the list, you also rotate this Node. Rotation works correctly as expected.

Comment: where is the null at? I try to output all the elements and I get no null. Do you mind pointing out which line is my mistake?

Comment: 1.) In LinkedList constructor, init head to null: head = null;
2.) Use my add() method.